# Unity3d: How to use dll from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, dll, unity-game-engine

I have written a dll in C# to perform several tasks for my game. I can successfully use that dll when I use it from a C# script in Unity. But when I use the dll from Javascript, it gives this error:

**Namespace 'MyLibrary' not found, maybe you forgot to add an assembly reference?**

I have placed MyLibrary.dll under Assets folder. This is how I access it from C#:

```
using MyLibrary;
```

This is how I access it from Javascript:

```
import MyLibrary;
```

So, I can use it from C#, but how can I also use it from Javascript?

Comment: You need to add a reference to the dll

Comment: Kindly tell me how? Because in C#, I can use it without adding a reference.

Comment: You're thinking of "Unityscript".  It is no longer available in Unity. You must change to c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NATIVE PLUGIN**:

***C#***:

```
[DllImport ("PluginName")]
private static extern float functionName ();
```

***JavaScript***:

```
@DllImport (DLLName)
static private function functionName () : float {};
```

**MANAGED PLUGIN**:

***C#***:

```
using MyLibrary;
```

***JavaScript***:

Go to your project directory, look for **YourProjectName.CSharp.csproj**

Find it, open it and add  `<Reference Include="MyLibrary">` into it then save it. Restart Unity and Visual Studio.

Put the DLL into the Assets folder.